# Query to show which games which friends don't have

Tags: database, ms-access

I have [three tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Ke4.png) set up in Access. I want to make a query that shows which games someone **doesn't have in common** with me.

I tried using an unmatched query, but that didn't work since each person has at least one game in common with me.

I guess I'm unsure how to handle this. The GameTimePlayed table basically has the opposite of the information I want to query, so is it possible to query that and add a "Not" conditional to "GameName" or something?

This is for a final project for class, and isn't due for about another month. I don't expect anyone to answer this for me, but even just a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Everything I've tried to find so far is basically about unmatched queries, which did not work for me.

---

**--EDIT TO PROVIDE MORE INFO--**

I have all of the games in FavoriteGames. However, not all of my friends (PersonID) have all of my FavoriteGames. I'd like a query to show a record of FirstName, LastName, GameName, for each PersonID, for each GameName that he/she does not have.

> **Expected Behavior Example:** PersonID 10 only has one GameName in common with me. The query should return five records for PersonID 10
>   (every game except Rocket League).

**Sample Data:**

[tbl_FavoriteGames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be0C8.png)

[tbl_FriendsWithGame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPLq7.png)

[tbl_GameTimePlayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/endWN.png)

**GameName** is the *Primary Key* for ***tbl_FavoriteGames***

**PersonID** is the *Primary Key* for ***tbl_FriendsWithGame***

**PersonID**, **GameName** *Foreign Keys* form a *Composite Primary Key* for ***tbl_GameTimePlayed***

This is the closest I have gotten so far (still way off though) in that it removes the specified GameName:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_GameTimePlayed
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM tbl_FriendsWithGame
  WHERE tbl_GameTimePlayed.PersonID = tbl_FriendsWithGame.PersonID
    AND tbl_GameTimePlayed.GameName = tbl_FavoriteGames.GameName
);
```

It prompts me to enter a GameName (no idea why). When I enter a GameName, it returns all records that don't have that specific GameName.

This returns 6 games for each person, whether or not the person actually has that game. Could be useful since it contains the people/games that aren't in common.

```
SELECT PersonID, GameName
FROM tbl_FriendsWithGame, tbl_FavoriteGames
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT PersonID FROM tbl_GameTimePlayed WHERE GameName = tbl_GameTimePlayed.GameName);
```

I tried "WHERE NOT EXISTS" and that returned 0 results.

---

**--SECOND EDIT: SOLVED!!--**

I took a fresh look at the problem today, and figured it out! I used the code mentioned above to query (**qry_AllPeopleAllGames**) a list of all of the games, for all of the people (so **6 entries per person**):

```
SELECT PersonID, GameName
FROM tbl_FriendsWithGame, tbl_FavoriteGames
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT PersonID FROM tbl_GameTimePlayed WHERE GameName = tbl_GameTimePlayed.GameName);
```

Then, I made another query that compared the qry_AllPeopleAllGames list to my tbl_GameTimePlayed (which is the list of people, games they actually own, and hours played) and spit out a list of FirstName & LastInitial and GameName that don't exist in the real list:

```
SELECT [tbl_FriendsWithGame]![FirstName] & " " & [tbl_FriendsWithGame]![LastInitial] AS FullName, GameName

FROM qry_AllPeopleAllGames INNER JOIN tbl_FriendsWithGame ON qry_AllPeopleAllGames.PersonID = tbl_FriendsWithGame.PersonID

WHERE ((NOT Exists (SELECT PersonID, GameName

FROM tbl_GameTimePlayed

WHERE qry_AllPeopleAllGames.PersonID = tbl_GameTimePlayed.PersonID AND qry_AllPeopleAllGames.GameName = tbl_GameTimePlayed.GameName
)));
```

****NOTE:**** The first part of the SELECT is not needed, I just used it for easier viewing in my actual query results (showing first name/last initial in one field).

I'm really excited that I figured this out! I'm sure there are better/more efficient ways to do this, and if you want to share, please let me know!

Comment: Hint: research "Not In" subqueries

Comment: I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Used_By_Already I am really sorry for having such a low-quality post, it was really inconsiderate of me. I just updated my post with a lot more information, hopefully it is useful for anyone who is willing to help.

Comment: I figured it out! @tomredfern I ended up using "NOT EXISTS" but I'm sure "NOT IN" would have worked too.

Answer (score 1):

I included this in my initial post, but I'll post this as the answer as well.

I took a fresh look at the problem today, and figured it out! Last night while trying to test random possible solutions, I accidently made a query that lists all of the games, for all of the people (so **6 entries per person**). Today, I used it as part of the solution, **qry_AllPeopleAllGames**:

```
SELECT PersonID, GameName
FROM tbl_FriendsWithGame, tbl_FavoriteGames
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT PersonID FROM tbl_GameTimePlayed WHERE GameName = tbl_GameTimePlayed.GameName);
```

Then, I made another query that compared the **qry_AllPeopleAllGames** list to my **tbl_GameTimePlayed**, which is the real list of people/games/hours played.

It returns the **FirstName&LastInitial** and the **GameName** for each PersonID/GameName combo that **doesn't** appear in the **tbl_GameTimePlayed** table. Here is the code:

```
SELECT [tbl_FriendsWithGame]![FirstName] & " " & [tbl_FriendsWithGame]![LastInitial] AS FullName, GameName

FROM qry_AllPeopleAllGames INNER JOIN tbl_FriendsWithGame ON qry_AllPeopleAllGames.PersonID = tbl_FriendsWithGame.PersonID

WHERE ((NOT Exists (SELECT PersonID, GameName

FROM tbl_GameTimePlayed

WHERE qry_AllPeopleAllGames.PersonID = tbl_GameTimePlayed.PersonID AND qry_AllPeopleAllGames.GameName = tbl_GameTimePlayed.GameName
)));
```

**NOTE:** The first part of the SELECT is not needed, I just used it for easier viewing in my actual query results (showing first name/last initial in one field).

I'm really excited that I figured this out! I'm sure there are better/more efficient ways to do this, and if you want to share, **please let me know!**

Answer (score 0):

You need a dataset of all possible pairs of friends/games in order to determine which games each friend does not have. Do you have a tbl_Friends? Consider:

Query1:
`SELECT tblFriends.ID, tbl_FavoriteGames.ID FROM tblFriends, tbl_FavoriteGames;`

That is a Cartesian query - without JOIN clause every record of each table will associate with each record of other table.

Query2:
`SELECT Query1.tblFriends.ID, Query1.tbl_FavoriteGames.ID
FROM tbl_FriendsWithGame RIGHT JOIN Query1 ON (tbl_FriendsWithGame.GameID = Query1.tbl_FavoriteGames.ID) AND (tbl_FriendsWithGame.FriendID = Query1.tblFriends.ID) WHERE tbl_FriendsWithGame.GameID IS NULL;`

Or if you don't have tbl_Friends
`SELECT DISTINCT tbl_FriendsWithGame.FriendID, tbl_FavoriteGames.ID
FROM tbl_FavoriteGames, tbl_FriendsWithGame;`

Then adjust Query2.